# Joins vs multiple selects

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing a fairly simple system where users can find computers by searching by option type. I want to search by brand, model, and "options".

Essentially I have 5 tables in this scenario-

1. brand
2. model
3. selection
4. options_group
5. options

The selection table is a multi-column lookup table containing:

- brand_id
- model_id
- options_group_id

The options_group table is a lookup table with an ID for "groups of options" and an entry for each option_id.

Basically, the options_group table allows for lots of entries to have the same group of options without storing it more than once.

Right. So. I want to select a specific selection of parts that generates a table:

- brand
- model
- options

where "options" is generated based off the options_group.

My question is this: Do I do this with multiple select statements, where I select just from the selection table first, and then use options_group to do a second select and get all of the options for each row, or do I do a join and get a table with lots of rows?

Before you suggest it, I'm not finding that any of the other answers on SO are answering this exact question.

Or is there some other, better way to do it? I read that joins are orders of magnitude faster than multiple selects, but parsing it at the end could take more time.

Comment: poorly described problem. i can't read beyond the half-way point. must resist downvote...

Comment: in other  words, would it kill you to copy/paste the output of `describe` tables?

Comment: I guess this is more hypothetical (uhhh... in that I haven't created the DB yet). Basically, in a many-to-one relationship, do you use multiple selects when selecting multiple rows from the "one" table, or do you use joins and have duplicate rows from the "one" table?

Comment: And I'm not asking about efficiency, I'm asking about 'better practice', which I can't seem to find anywhere

Comment: if that's the case you could always construct a simpler example than the one you chose the ask the question with. i think i understand the question in a 2-table master-detail context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a single statement with `select distinct` to weed out duplicates. the relational-calculus / relational-algebra that underlies SQL automatically eliminates duplicates as part of the `project` operator. however, SQL by default does not do so and requires you to use `distinct`. because underlying relational theory encourages a single statement, and it fits neatly into the operators, i recommend it as a best practice.

with two tables `parent (id)` and `child (id, parent_id, property)` do `select distinct parent.id from parent join child on parent.id = child.id where child.property in ("X", "Z");`

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for good practice, I'll throw in the fact that this doesn't have to be a db-only solution. It's good practice to cache static/lookup data (sounds like models and/or parts don't change very often) in the app layer or something like memcached, etc, and it will save you the joins and reduce your resultset size.

Comment: Thanks, its the subtleties that really help. I'll keep this in mind.